# Looking for a wireless soil moisture sensor

Tags: sensors, bluetooth, wifi

I am new to arduino and have a basic question. I want to build a sprinkler controller system for my lawn which would detect moisture in the lawn soil and automatically starts the sprinkler controller to water the lawn when moisture in the lawn soil reaches a certain level. I am looking for soil moisture sensors that would be installed in the lawn soil and wirelessly transmit the moisture level to my arduino in the house. Any ideas where I can find these sensors?

Answer (score 2):

The project is very much possible but it will be easier if you attach the moisture sensor directly to the arduino and add a wifi shield or a bluetooth shield to the arduino itself and make it communicate with computer or phone. You could also program the arduino to directly water the plants if it finds that they dont have much moisture. You will rarely find a sensor that transmits data wirelessly and still be economically feasible. The Sparkfun SEN-13322 moisture sensor is good for the purpose but again connect it to arduino direclty.

Comment: so how do I read the moisture in the lawn soil?  I can't put the sensor and arduino in the lawn so not sure what you are suggesting?

Comment: @JStorage I cant figure out why you cant put the arduino and the sensor in the lawn. For all such projects that I have seen arduino is encased in a box that protects it from rain etc. and the its connected to the sensor  and kept in the lawn. But also if you want this project to be messy you can actually wire the sensor in the lawn to the arduino inside but that will be a little too messy. Simply keep the arduino in a plastic box and attatch the sensor and keep it in the lawn.